# Samung LCD monitor small flashes then shuts off

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display

I just got a new PC and monitor.  The PC is a dell precision 690 which is used.  I got a new samung 27in LCD monitor. Fresh Windows 7 install.  Belkin DVI to HDMI cable.

There are small glimmers, almost half fades that happen frequently (~0.5 Hz, but not regular). Every few minutes (twice during the typing of this description) or so the monitor shuts off.  It is not the computer's power settings as I have shut them off and moving the mouse or typing does not turn the monitor back on.  Either power cycling the monitor or unplugging the DVI/HDMI cable from either end turns the monitor back on for a time but the problem continues.

Any ideas?  I feel it's not the video card as power cycling the monitor fixes it. So I'm thinking it's either the monitor or the cable. Anyone come across a similar situation.

Thanks in advance.